# how to open a file without using Ivy

Tags: find-file, ivy

Under most operations, when I open a file with `C-x C-f` Ivy pops up my narrowing list at the bottom and its great.

However, I have a current situation when I'd like to open a file on a remote host in a directory that has 60,000 files in it.  So when I `C-x C-f` into that directory over tramp, it takes an awfully long time until I can find the file I am looking for.  Sometimes, though I know what the file name is and I'd just like to type it and not have Ivy butt in so that I can get on with it.  How would I bet go about doing this?

Comment: No: `ivy` hooks into `completing-read`.

Comment: You can toggle ivy with `M-x ivy-mode` and then do as @phils suggested and do `M-x find-file`.

Comment: Or indeed `C-x C-f`, I expect.  I've deleted my erroneous suggestion in any case.

Comment: I have to turn `ivy-mode` off in order to edit TRAMP paths to add multiple hops.  Because of key bindings set to use `counsel` I cannot use `C-x C-f` because `counsel` butts in and calls `ivy-completing-read`!  Instead, you have to do `M-x find-file` after disabling `ivy-mode`

Comment: indeed this does work, calling M-x find-file after disabling ivy-mode.  Perhaps not ideal, but it works

Comment: Did you find a good way to work in that huge directory of files?

Comment: @gregoryg, I haven't had a chance to come back to it yet.  In something of an ebb with that work

Answer (score 4):

In default Ivy configurations, `C-x C-f` is bound to `counsel-find-file` which will invoke `ivy-completing-read` even if global `ivy-mode` is turned off!

Rather than going through the clumsy steps of disabling Ivy, calling the non-Counsel `find-file`, then turning Ivy back on, I have implemented this solution.

In the given use case of many files, you can enter a portion of the file name, then use `TAB` to get completion on the matching set.

```lisp
(defun gjg/find-file-no-ivy ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ivy-state ivy-mode))
    (ivy-mode -1)
    (call-interactively 'find-file)
    (ivy-mode ivy-state)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x F") 'gjg/find-file-no-ivy) ; steals key from set-fill-column
```

The function restores the state of `ivy-mode`.  Bind to any key that works for you!